# How to create bitmap via Powershell

Tags: .net, image, powershell, bitmap, system.drawing

I'd like to learn to create/edit images with Powershell.
Help me, please, to create bitmap image, fill it with some color, set color of some pixel to some other color and save image to file.

***EDIT:*** I tried following code, but got a black bitmap

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
$bmp = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap(320, 240)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 100; $i++)
{
   for ($j = 0; $j -lt 100; $j++)
   {
     $bmp.SetPixel($i, $j, 1000)
   }
}

$bmp.Save("f:\Temp\bmp.bmp")
ii f:\Temp\bmp.bmp
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SetPixel` takes a final argument of type `System.Drawing.Color`.  Powershell is converting the integer `1000` into a `Color` object, and this ends up with basically a "black" color:

```
PS > [system.drawing.color] 1000

R             : 0
G             : 3
B             : 232
A             : 0       # A is "Alpha", aka opacity. A = 0 -> full transparent
IsKnownColor  : False
IsEmpty       : False
IsNamedColor  : False
IsSystemColor : False
Name          : 3e8
```

You can either pass a string corresponding to [a known named color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_properties.aspx) (e.g. `'Red'`), or create a custom RGB color from either `[System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($r, $g, $b)` or `[System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($a, $r, $g, $b)`, where all arguments can be from 0 to 255 inclusive.  See the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh.aspx).

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 100; $i++)
{
   for ($j = 0; $j -lt 100; $j += 2)
   {
     $bmp.SetPixel($i, $j, 'Red')
     $bmp.SetPixel($i, $j + 1, [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(0, 100, 200))
   }
}
```